# Is it possible to mock a function called from inside module in jest?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, mocking

I have a TypeScript module with two functions: foo() calls bar(). I want to mock bar() and call foo() from the unit test. I tried this:

foo.ts:

```
export function bar(){
  throw 'not implemented'
}

export function foo(){
  return bar();
}
```

foo.test.ts:

```
import * as foo from './foo'

test('TODO', () => {
  jest.spyOn(foo, 'bar').mockReturnValue('quux')
  expect(foo.foo()).toBe('quux')
});
```

But I got an error:

```
 FAIL  ./foo.test.ts
  ✕ TODO (4 ms)

  ● TODO

    thrown: "not implemented"

      1 | import * as foo from './foo'
      2 |
    > 3 | test('TODO', () => {
        | ^
      4 |   jest.spyOn(foo, 'bar').mockReturnValue('quux')
      5 |   expect(foo.foo()).toBe('quux')
      6 | });

      at Object.<anonymous> (foo.test.ts:3:1)
      at TestScheduler.scheduleTests (node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:333:13)
```

It appears that foo() is somehow bypassing the mock. How can I make it use the mock instead of the real bar()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this change foo() to call exports.bar() instead of bar():

```
export function foo(){
  return exports.bar();
}
```

foo() in your example is bypassing the mock because there are two namespaces: the module and the exports object. When the reference to bar() is resolved JavaScript and TypeScript search for it in the module namespace but Jest can only spy on the exports object and can't change the contents of the module.

One possible solution is to explicitly lookup the identifiers you want to mock via the exports object as demonstrated above.

I found this approach here: https://medium.com/welldone-software/jest-how-to-mock-a-function-call-inside-a-module-21c05c57a39f#576f

Comment: Namespaces also work in this case

Answer (score 1):

try this refactor:

foo.ts:

```
const fn = {
  bar(): unknown | void {
    throw "not implemented";
  },

  foo() {
    return fn.bar();
  },
};

export default fn
```

foo.test.ts:

```
import functionsUnderTest from "./foo";

beforeEach(() => {
  jest.spyOn(functionsUnderTest, "bar").mockReturnValue("quux");
});

test("TODO", () => {
  expect(functionsUnderTest.foo()).toBe("quux");
});
```

issue with namespaces is solved in this way